# How to change background of sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a landing page with sticky header.

When user start scroll and the page displays `.second-section` `.header` element should change the `background-color` property. How to do it right?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: var(--header-height);
}

:root {
  --header-height: 100px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);

  border-bottom: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.main {
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.section__item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.first-section {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.first-section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first-section-left__text {
  margin: 0 0 70px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.first-section-left__button {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.second-section {
  background-color: azure;
}

.galery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.galery_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(12) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">header</header>
<main class="main">
  <section class="section first-section">
    <div class="section__item first-section-left">
      <p class="first-section-left__text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci assumenda optio nesciunt deleniti voluptas. Amet ratione, necessitatibus deserunt natus ipsum ea magni debitis minima quod eum. Vel at praesentium magnam.
      </p>
      <button class="first-section-left__button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="section__item galery">
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/buildings/" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/daily" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/weekly" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/daily" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?sun" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?flowers" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?cars" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?car" alt="title" />
      </div>
      <div class="galery_item">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?boss" alt="title" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="section second-section">2</section>
  <section class="section third-section">3</section>
</main>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/perevezencev/pen/NJepYq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use javascript for this.
Here is a JS function that should works, with a new css class:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll',detectScroll);

function detectScroll() {
    let section2 = document.querySelector('.second-section');
    let header = document.querySelector('.header');
    if (section2.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > 0 && section2.getBoundingClientRect().top < document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
        header.classList.add('bg-red');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('bg-red');
    }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: var(--header-height);
}

:root {
  --header-height: 100px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);

  border-bottom: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: #f86;
}

.main {
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.section__item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.first-section {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.first-section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first-section-left__text {
  margin: 0 0 70px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.first-section-left__button {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.second-section {
  background-color: azure;
}

.galery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.galery_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(12) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">header</header>
    <main class="main">
      <section class="section first-section">
        <div class="section__item first-section-left">
          <p class="first-section-left__text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci
            assumenda optio nesciunt deleniti voluptas. Amet ratione,
            necessitatibus deserunt natus ipsum ea magni debitis minima quod
            eum. Vel at praesentium magnam.
          </p>
          <button class="first-section-left__button">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section__item galery">
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/buildings/"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/daily" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/weekly"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/daily"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?sun" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?flowers" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?cars" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?car" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?boss" alt="title" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section second-section">2</section>
      <section class="section third-section">3</section>
    </main>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your codepen's javascript section. You also need to ensure you have selected the jquery library from the settings menu on the codepen javascript tab (codepen's documentation can help you with this). This should get you started.

Cheers

```js
$(window).on('load scroll resize orientationchange', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 67) { 
        $('.header').css("background-color", "transparent");
    }
    else{
     
        $('.header').css("background-color", "rgba(55, 55, 62, 0.6)");
    }
  });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;

  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-padding-top: var(--header-height);
}

:root {
  --header-height: 100px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);

  border-bottom: 1px solid rebeccapurple;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.main {
}

.section {
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height));
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.section__item {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

.first-section {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.first-section-left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.first-section-left__text {
  margin: 0 0 70px 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.first-section-left__button {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.second-section {
  background-color: azure;
}

.galery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(80px, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.galery_item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(4) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(5) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(7) {
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(8) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}

.galery_item:nth-child(12) {
  grid-column-end: span 3;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">header</header>
    <main class="main">
      <section class="section first-section">
        <div class="section__item first-section-left">
          <p class="first-section-left__text">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci
            assumenda optio nesciunt deleniti voluptas. Amet ratione,
            necessitatibus deserunt natus ipsum ea magni debitis minima quod
            eum. Vel at praesentium magnam.
          </p>
          <button class="first-section-left__button">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="section__item galery">
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/buildings/"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/daily" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/category/nature/weekly"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img
              src="https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/daily"
              alt="title"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?water" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?sun" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?flowers" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?cars" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?car" alt="title" />
          </div>
          <div class="galery_item">
            <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/weekly?boss" alt="title" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section class="section second-section">2</section>
      <section class="section third-section">3</section>
    </main>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```